# Magnitude of rotation between two quaternions

Tags: rotation, quaternions

I have a quaternion for an object's starting rotation, and a quaternion for an object's ending rotation, and I am SLERPing the shortest rotation between the two.

How can I figure out the magnitude of the rotation between the object's start and end rotations?

Comment: also see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90081/quaternion-distance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's introduce two quaternions `qStart` and `qEnd`. Magnitude of rotation between them can be expressed as a quaternion:

```
qRot = qEnd * qStart.inversed();
```

and the exact angle of rotation can be extracted as:

```
2*atan2(qRot.vec.length(), qRot.w);
```